# Once vs. wants pronunciation?

Tags: pronunciation, phonetics

What's the difference between how once and wants are pronounced? I don't hear a difference- is there one?

Comment: There is a difference, though obviously not the way you and your milieu pronounce it. I suggest you look in a dictionary, preferably an online one with audible pronunciation.

Comment: There is definitely a difference in my dialect (Northeastern US) although it is small.  The vowel sound is slightly different (sort of "ah" vs. "uh") and the /ts/ of *wants* is distinct from the /s/ of *once*.

Comment: In my AmE dialect, they are indistinguishable.

Comment: Central Ohio for the last 50 years (grew up here).
I wuhnt one.
He wuhnts two. I came here because somebody asked me what I said, "Once what??" And I realized it is the same vowel sound! Weird!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are quite similar, but the vowel sounds are different.

Regional dialects may vary, but I think *once* rhymes with "dunce", whereas *wants* rhymes with "haunts."

Comment: As I hear *wants* it rhymes with *nonce*. Midwestern by way of New England.

Comment: In my dialect (Northeastern US, specifically NYC) *wants* doesn't sound like *haunts* at all.  *wants* is very distinctly WUHnts and *haunts* is HAWnts.

Comment: @stangdon: *WUHnts* ... I've never heard that pronunciation, or else never noticed it if I did.

Comment: @stangdon - So it seems like you view the O.P.'s words more like homophones than I do. Interesting.

Comment: @Robusto - Is it more like *WAWnts* in your regiolect?

Comment: @stangdon: Not at all. That pronunciation I associate with western Pennsylvania, or maybe Boston (where I lived for nearly three decades). But I have heard it. As I said above, *wants* rhymes with *nonce* for me.

Comment: @J.R. - Not exact homophones, but pretty close.  My initial inclination was to say "don't be silly, of course they're different", but listening closely, I have to admit they're quite close.

Comment: @Robusto - Interesting.  To me, "nonce" begins with a more distinct *NAAH* sound than "wants".  Unfortunately I am running out of good phonetic/phonological terminology to describe these things.  :-(  I should really learn IPA one of these days.

Comment: Interestingly, I just Skyped a friend in California and she says it half the time to rhyme with *nonce* and half with *once*. Go figure. When she says "I want it" it sounds like "I won it" to me. She grew up in SoCal, too, so who knows? Sometimes it can be hard to distinguish regional accents from idiosyncratic ones.

Comment: Chipping in from Australia; I pronounce them as once/dunce and wants/nonce.

Comment: I use the vowel /ɒ/ for both words, but RP uses /ʌ/ in "once" and /ɒ/ in "wants".

Answer (score 3):

JR's answer focuses more on the vowels, I'm going to explain what happens to the consonants in word pairs like *wants/once*.

Actually, both *once* and *wants* are usually pronounced with a /t/, but we may not realise it whilst speaking fast.
Other word that are usually pronounced the same include *prince/prints*, *deviance/deviants*, *innocence/innocents* etc.

So what happens here?

There are loads of English words that contain a nasal (/n m ŋ/) followed by a fricative (/s f ʃ θ/ etc). For instance, *once* /wʌns/.

Here's a good explanation from [*English after RP* by Geoff Lindsey](https://books.google.com/books/about/English_After_RP.html?id=6nSKDwAAQBAJ&source=kp_book_description&redir_esc=y):

> The /n/ is a stop sound, which means that the oral airflow of speech is stopped; the tongue blade is held against the alveolar ridge while breath is re-directed through the nose. As /n/ changes to /s/ [which is an oral consonant i.e the air comes out through the mouth], airflow must be switched from nasal to oral, and at the same time the stoppage at the alveolar ridge must be released,
>
> [...]
>
> Epenthesis is more likely if the fricative after the nasal is voiceless, when the articulatory system has an additional voicing change to handle [i.e. moving from a voiced sound like /n/ to a voiceless one like /s/]. It’s less likely if the fricative is at the beginning
> of a stressed syllable, e.g. *inˈsane* [not **in[t]sane*].

(pp 63-64)

And it results in an epenthetic stop (/t p k/), homorganic (having the same place of articulation) with the nasal and creates [wʌnts] in this case which may be indistinguishable from 'wants' in some accents (not all). Another common example is *prince* which is usually pronounced the same as *prints*. Epenthetic stops between a nasal and a fricative are very common and natural and may be barely perceptible.

This phenomenon is called [epenthesis (excrescence).](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epenthesis)

Other examples include len[k]th, stren[k]th, youn[k]ster etc.
Bilabial examples would be warm[p]th, Thom[p]son, some[p]thing etc.

In many varieties of English, *once* and *wants* have the same vowel, so both of them may be indistinguishable.